# How to start a new application in the background in GNOME?

Tags: gnome

Is it possible to start a new application with the lowest [z-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order) in GNOME? Normally a new application is started with the highest z-index overlapping all already opened windows. I want to start a new long starting application in the background so that it does not pop up unexpectedly overlapping current window when it finishes loading.